# Error when connecting NetLogo 6.0 and R

Tags: java, r, netlogo

Trying to call Netlogo 6.0 from R 3.3.2 on MacOSX 10.11.6 (Capitan)

After,

```
library("RNetLogo") 

nl.path <- getwd()

NLStart(nl.path)
```

gives me the following exception/error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/nlogo/workspace/Controllable
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
at RJavaClassLoader.findClass(RJavaClassLoader.java:383)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 2 more
```

It seems some kind of problem with Java, RJavaClassLoader,

I would ask you to help me solve this issue.

Thank you very much

Comment: The issue is currently discussed by the NetLogo team at CCL and they are trying to understand more about the features people find important about the rJava package. If anyone is interested in having the CCL support this, you can contribute to the discussion here: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/1282

Answer (score 1):

RNetLogo is built against the NetLogo 5 API, which means it can't be used with NetLogo 6. Please send an enhancement request to the NetLogo team if you would like NetLogo to officially support RNetLogo in NetLogo 6 and future NetLogo releases.